# Hide check box from controller-MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can i hide/show a check box based on a value obtained from controller.
I am using the given below code for check box

```
   <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m =>m.IncludeCallWithNoAgents) %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view model could contain a property which would be set by the controller action and which should indicate whether this checkbox should be shown or not:

```
<% if (Model.ShouldShowCheckBox) { %>
    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IncludeCallWithNoAgents) %>
<% } %>
```